# Airflow DAG doesn't run with CRON format '30 20 * * 2,3'

Tags: airflow

I have Airflow schedule to run with UTC date format. When schedule_interval = '00 12 * * *' for example, the code runs everyday at 12, but when I change schedule_interval =  '30 20 * * 2,3' which means run at 20:30 every Tuesday and Wednesday, my Dag doesn't run at all.

How to set up the DAG to run on Tuesday and Wednesday?

Answer (score 0):

you have to crate two schedule . one for Tuesday and Wednesday

Below is how you can create format for scheduler.

Use the hash sign to prefix a comment

```
# +---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  +------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  +---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  +------- month (1 - 12)
# |  |  |  |  +---- day of week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  *  command to be executed
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I tried two schedule :  schedule_interval = '00 12 * * 2' and  schedule_interval = '00 12 * * 3', but none of them work. The issue is when I added day of week, my Dag doesn't pick up. The only option that works is everyday like  schedule_interval = '00 12 * * *'. Any idea why ?

Comment: It is very strange . how you are verifying that it is not picking .

Comment: Please share logs https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.1/scheduler.html

Comment: I verified it from Airflow UI dashboard, nothing is happening when I set schedule interval   '00 12 * * 3'

Comment: weight till time pass

Comment: What do you mean by until time pass? Like min , hour or day ?